# Prevent asynchronous call when dealing with Cursor class

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have the method below in my WPF application. I wrapped it in a Dispatcher.Invoke call because the service that opens the window runs on a thread other than the main thread. So far this works.

But the problem is with my Cursor. It seems that the call to OpenMimic executes asynchronously, so my cursor turns into an hourglass but for a split second only. Then 2 or 3 seconds later, the OpenMimic method opens a window.
How can I show this so that the Cursor stays as an hourglass until the OpenMimic call is completed?

```
    [OnExecuteMethod]
    public void OpenAlarmListMimic()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
                ViewsIntegerationService.OpenMimic(@"GTCS\GCS\mmc_AlarmList", "", "", 2, ThisMimic.Context, null);
            }
            finally
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you use the debugger are you sure it is running the finally block? Either `OpenMimic` is taking a split second to return (if the class is your code could you show the code of `OpenMimic` to us), a exeption is being thrown right away causing it to go to the finally, or it actually is waiting but some code somewhere else is unsetting your OverrideCursor value.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, using the debugger I confirm that it is running the finally block. I added a catch statement, but there is no exception. The window actually opens a few seconds later, but after the finally code is executed. This is the heart of my problem.

Comment: In that case the problem is in the code for `ViewsIntegerationService.OpenMimic`, you need to include the code for that function in your question as a edit for us to be able to help you figure out why it is not working.

Comment: The problem is that this OpenMimic method calls an external assembly that I do not have code access to. There is an external class that gets loaded by MEF and the call to this method is all I can do to open the window. But what can cause this method to return immediately? Even before the UI opens the window.

Comment: If in the call chain to the 3rd party dll a async function is called without awaiting it or along the chain there is an "async void" used it would cause it. That's why we need to see at least the method signatures of the methods or a link to the documentation so we can see what the other options are.